# Jquery Validate with Custom DatePicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate, coffeescript

Right now I have a custom datepicker that I'm trying to do validation. Specifically, I'm trying to check whether a startDate field comes before endDate field.

When I click on my datepicker and populate my input field, I need to click on my field and then away from the field before the message will come up. I think this is because jquery validate is listening for a keyup event, rather than a change event in the input field.

This is my code (written in coffee, but I'll accept javascript answers) -

```
validateSearchForm:=>
$(@el).find("#searchForm").validate({
  rules:{
    startDateInputBox:{
      dateISO:true,
      lessThan: true
    },
    endDateInputBox:{
      dateISO:true
      lessThan: true
    }
    searchPurposeBox:"required"
 }
});
```

Less than is -

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod "lessThan", ((value, element) ->
  validDateFormat = /(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})/
  startDateInput = $("#startTime").val()
  endDateInput = $("#endTime").val()
  startDateMatch = startDateInput.match(validDateFormat)
  endDateMatch = endDateInput.match(validDateFormat)
  startDateYear = startDateMatch[1]
  startDateMonth = startDateMatch[2]
  startDateDay = startDateMatch[3]
  endDateYear = endDateMatch[1]
  endDateMonth = endDateMatch[2]
  endDateDay = endDateMatch[3]
  startDate = new Date(startDateYear,startDateMonth,startDateDay)
  endDate = new Date(endDateYear,endDateMonth,endDateDay)
  if endDate < startDate
    return false
  return true
), "Start time has to be before end time"
```

How do I make it so that when I click on my datepicker and populate my field with a wrong value, the error message comes up instantly? I've tried onkeyup, but that does not fix the problem.

Thanks

Comment: Check out [this plugin](https://github.com/elclanrs/jq-idealforms) if you want custom datepicker validation.

Answer (score 0):

what I have done before is hook into the onClose event of the datepicker (if it has one, I know the jQuery UI datepicker has onClose) and then call something like

```
$("#searchForm input[name='startDateInputBox']").valid()
```